# Sylius New Field on Taxon Forms not Saving

Tags: taxonomy, sylius

I've added a new field to the Taxon entity, and have the new field showing up on the form on the edit Taxon page in the admin panel. My problem is that I can't get my new field to save to the Taxon. I receive a success message, but only existing Taxon fields save, while my new field clears. Here's my code (note I'm making changes to Sylius core rather than extending, as proof of concept. Once I have this working, I'll extend properly):

**src/Sylius/Bundle/TaxonomyBundle/Form/Type/TaxonType.php:**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('translations', 'sylius_translations', [
            'type' => 'sylius_taxon_translation',
            'label' => 'sylius.form.taxon.name',
        ])
        ->add('my_new_field', 'text', [
            'label' => 'My New Field',
            'required' => false
        ])
        ->addEventSubscriber(new AddCodeFormSubscriber())
        ->addEventSubscriber(new BuildTaxonFormSubscriber($builder->getFormFactory())
    );

}
```

**src/Sylius/Component/Core/Model/Taxon.php:**

> protected $my_new_field;

and

```
public function getMyNewField() {
    return $this->my_new_field;
}

public function setMyNewField($myNewField) {
    $this->my_new_field = $myNewField;
}
```

After updating the Taxon model, I ran doctrine:diff and then ran the migration to add my new field to the model. I can confirm, the field was added to the database.

The field also shows up on Taxons now, on the edit screen. I can input text into the field and it posts correctly, but does not ever save to the taxon.

I would think I'm missing some controller logic, but it seems that taxons go through the standard ResourceController's updateAction() and I haven't been able to figure out how to make this aware of the new field which needs to be saved.

Comment: Could you please provide also your mapping file for the `Taxon` entity?

Comment: All I needed was a nudge in the right direction. Thank you so much for your help, your comment got it all working for me. If you post an answer saying I was missing my ORM mappings in: src/Sylius/Bundle/TaxonomyBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/model/Taxon.orm.xml I'll accept it. Thanks again! Quick note, I was also the properties on this model: src/Sylius/Component/Taxonomy/Model/Taxon.php. It seems like having them in src/Sylius/Component/Core/Model/Taxon.php wasn't enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably missing ORM mapping in `Taxon.orm.xml` file.

Remember:

- if you've added your properties on `Sylius\Component\Taxonomy\Model\Taxon` you have to update `src/Sylius/Bundle/TaxonomyBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/model/Taxon.orm.xml`.
- if you've added your properties on `Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Taxon` you have to update `src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/model/Taxon.orm.xml`

It's also probably better to extend `Taxon` model from **Core** component.